# Why are maps in Indian apps like Uber, Google Maps so inaccurate?

Tags: gps, geolocation

I've been using some popular taxi-hailing apps like Uber and OLA in India and the same, Uber, in USA. The location of cars, where they're moving and my position on the app's map are always off. So much so, I'd need to call the driver to tell them where I'm at. From this Quora thread I was able to narrow the problem to be in use of Maps API or GPS signals.

The Quora post: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-GPS-in-India-so-inaccurate

The parody video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjBM-zSq3NU

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the problem is caused by your device or the capability of GPS in your area. newer phones can use 10's of GPS's to locate themselves this is actually called AGPS. However, older phones use three cell towers (not GPS) in order to triangulate your position. While, this method was fairly accurate it was known to be more than a couple of feet off on occasion. Even older phones, may even use only two cell towers, the problem here that the speed at which this data (light speed) allowed for a very large margin of error which could be your problem. Also, some phones without AGPS use only one GPS to locate, and this may also complicate things for you.

Comment: Nice approach to the problem here. However, I'm sure it's not that because I was on iPhone 6 with full 4G data coverage in the poshest location of a high-tech Indian city (Bangalore). Also, I happened to learn that this issue is also plaguing people in China for the same app and the same tendency of not relying on GPS exists due to the same issue.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's much to be done... I doubt its a problem with the device, and if it's working for other people I really can't see a solution here.